# Using $routeProvider for dynamic routing and compiling angular code

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dynamic, compilation, routes

this has been bugging me for days and i can't figure this out. 
i have a website that adds articles at certain points so i figured i shouldn't need to change the routing every time i add a page. so i added this to my project:

```
 $routeProvider.when ('/pages/:page', { templateUrl: 'page.html', controller: 'pageCtrl' });
```

then i use this for the pageCtrl:

```
 app.controller('pageCtrl', function ($scope, $http, $q, $routeParams, $sce, $location) {
  $http.get("partials/" + $routeParams.page + ".html")
  .then(function(ret) {
    $scope.content = $sce.trustAsHtml(ret.data);
  }, function(err) {
    $location.path("/404")
  });
 });
```

then in the webpage i put a

```
 <div ng-view ng-bind-html="content">{{content}}</div>
```

and all works well except when i put angular code in there. it seems that it will only parse regular html code but not the ng-stuff. i think i should put a $compile in there somewhere. but i tried all combinations i could think of but none work.

things i tried:

```
 $scope.content = $compile($sce.trustAsHtml(ret.data))($scope);

 var e=angular.element($sce.trustAsHtml(ret.data));
 c=$compile(e);
 $scope.content = c;
 c($scope);
```

and several others that didnt do anything at all..

what's the right way to add content in a view and have angular directive work properly?

Comment: Why can't you just add to your view: `<div ng-include="page"></div>` and set `$scope.page = $routeParams.page;`

Comment: i think ng-include only works at page-load. if you load the page in a route afterwards it will re-enter the controller until it runs into an error: 
`Error: error:infdig Infinite $digest Loop`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work well with `ng-include` within your `page.html` template:

page.html:

```
<h1>Page {{name}}</h1>
<div ng-include="contentUrl"></div>
```

Then your `pageCtrl` can set these to:

```
app.controller("pageCtrl", function($scope, $routeParams){
  $scope.name = $routeParams.page;
  $scope.contentUrl = $routeParams.page + ".html";
})
```

Here's a working [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/P6mLEBH6xmR308KdqGdl?p=preview)

Comment: actually that works like a charm. i think i tried that but got the infinite loop error. probably made a typo somewhere. copy/paste did the trick! thanks :)

Comment: quick addition. because this method doesn't detect whether the page actually exists, i added this to the controller to redirect it to my custom 404 page:
`  $scope.$on('$includeContentError', function(event) {
    $location.path("/404");
    console.log("Error");
  });`